# What is the difference between git merge --ff <commit> and git reset <commit> --mixed

Tags: git, git-merge, git-reset, fast-forward

If I want to update my local branch, say `master`, to the remote branch `gitlab/master`, I see two options:

- I can merge the local branch with the remote branch using a fast forward merge.
- I can use reset to move my branch to the position of the remote branch.

The first operation can be achieved in my SmartGit GUI by right-click: `merge`. The latter operation can be achieved by dragging the local branch marker to a new position.

Is there any technical difference between `git merge --ff <commit>` and `git reset <commit> --mixed`?

I admit that reset could also be used to move the local branch to another branch, which is not in the fast-forward way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the merge resolves as a fast-forward, there should be no differences, but if it's not the case:

- If you use `git merge`, you will have a merge commit and all commit from both branches.
- If you use `git reset`, you will have only commits from `gitlab/master` and no merge commit. The commits from `master` absent from `gitlab/master` will be uncommited (reset) but their content will be present in the working directory.

You can try this yourself, with the follwing two scenari:

(Initialisation, common two both scenari, we use `master` as `gitlab/master` and `branch1` as `master`)

```
# Common commit
git init
echo a > a; git add .; git commit -m"a"
# Commit on branch1
git checkout -b branch1
git init
echo b > b; git add .; git commit -m"b"
# Second commit on master
git checkout master~1
echo c > c; git add .; git commit -m"c"
```

(Merge scenario)

```
git checkout branch1
git merge master
```

(Reset scenario)

```
git checkout branch1
git reset master
```

Note also that both options `--ff`and `--mixed` are default options and can be omitted.

Comment: Doesn't `--ff` enforce a fast-forward merge, whereas no option allows a fast-forward merge or a merge commit?

Comment: Oh I see my fault. The enforcing option is `--ff-only`.

Answer (score 2):

As you noted in your own comment on [Ortomala Lokni's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46758479/1256452), you would need `--ff-only` to force an only-fast-forward operation.  The other important difference is that this kind of `git reset`:

1. always moves / reassigns `HEAD` (stop here if `--soft`);
2. optionally resets the index (stop here if `--mixed`);
3. optionally resets the work-tree (`--hard`).

Since you specifically asked for a `--mixed` reset, this kind of operation would leave the work-tree out of sync with the current commit and index.  A fast-forward "merge" (I put merge in quotes here since it's not really doing any merging) updates the work-tree.